# How to show Metric TSP in APX set of algorithms

Tags: algorithm, big-o, approximation

I know that Metric Travelling Salesman Problem is in the APX (approximable) set of algorithms, but I'm not sure how to show this?

I have been researching about it a little bit and have heard that you can show that Metric TSP is in APX by `giving a corresponding algorithm`.

What are the steps for this?

Comment: Christofides algorithm is the classic 3/2-approximation.

Comment: Hey Harold, thanks for the pointer; could you please give more insight

Comment: Such as what, isn't that already exactly what you wanted? It's an algorithm that works under your assumption (ie metric) that has an approximation ration bounded by a constant (3/2). There's a simpler algorithm with a worse constant bound if you want.

Comment: Sorry I misread your answer, thanks for pointing me in the right direction